# Como ativar uma class no botao html atraves do Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um botão `PAUSE/PLAY` e queria que ao clicar no `PAUSE` fosse ativada a `class .carousel-control-next-icon`.

Aqui o trecho do código que quero inbutir a `class: .carousel-control-next-icon` ao ser clicada.

```html
<label id="myBtn2" for="play">
 <i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>
```

Tentei fazer usando `onclick`, mas não consegui.

```css
      #player{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40%;
        right: 40px;
        z-index: 999;
      }
      .controls i{
        background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0%,#ddd 100%);
        padding: 11px 13px 11px 13px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .controls i{
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #178F5D;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 1s;
        transition: 100ms all ease;
      }
      .controls label {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #myBtn,
      #myBtn2 {
        display: none;
      }
      #play:checked ~ .controls #myBtn,
      #pause:checked ~ .controls #myBtn2 {
        display: block;
      }
      [name="player"] {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="player">
 <input type="radio" name="player" id="pause" checked>
 <input type="radio" name="player" id="play">
 <div class="controls">
   <label id="myBtn2" for="play"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
   <label id="myBtn" for="pause"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
              
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer atribuir a classe `.carousel-control-next-icon` no `<label>` ou no `<i>`?

Comment: @CmteCardeal quero atribuir no label id=myBtn2 porq se colocar no i acho q não da certo

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var btn2 = document.getElementById('myBtn2') 
  var showTag = document.querySelector('.controls') //pegar a div com class 'controls' sóp ara testarmos no final
  btn2.addEventListener('click', addClass)//Event Listener de click o mesmo evento de 'onclick' na tag html, (ao clicar executar a função addClass)

  function addClass() {
    if (btn2.getAttribute('class') == '.carousel-control-next-icon') {
     btn2.setAttribute('class', '.carousel-control-next-icon')
    } // Vai pegar/checar se o valor atributo class do label btn2 é igual a .carousel-control-next-icon, e se for ele apenas vai substituir pelo mesmo e não adicionar mais class
    else {
      btn2.setAttribute('class', '.carousel-control-next-icon')
    } //Caso a class do label btn2 não for igual a .carousel-cont... ele vai adicionar uma class. Adicionando na tag label um class=".carousel-control.next-icon"
    alert(showTag.innerHTML)// Só Para testar e conferir se a class está no label
  }
```

```css
          #player{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40%;
            right: 40px;
            z-index: 999;
          }
          .controls i{
            background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0%,#ddd 100%);
            padding: 11px 13px 11px 13px;
            border-radius: 50%;
          }
          .controls i{
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #178F5D;
            text-align: center;
            transition: 1s;
            transition: 100ms all ease;
          }
          .controls label {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
          }
          #myBtn,
          #myBtn2 {
            display: none;
          }
          #play:checked ~ .controls #myBtn,
          #pause:checked ~ .controls #myBtn2 {
            display: block;
          }
          [name="player"] {
            display: none;
          }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="player">
     <input type="radio" name="player" id="pause" checked>
     <input type="radio" name="player" id="play">
     <div class="controls">
       <label id="myBtn2" for="play"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
       <label id="myBtn" for="pause"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                  
     </div>
    </div>
```

E caso queira ficar Ativando e Desativando a class (apagando e criando-a) basta apenas colocar um `removeAttribute('class')`
***Exemplo:***

***OBS: Que caso queira ficar desativando e ativando a class do*** `<label id=myBtn2` ***e ativar apenas quando clica nele, você vai ter que colocar um*** `onclick` ***em html ou um `enventListener` em javascript para chamar a função addClass para o outro label o*** `<label id=myBtn` ***desativar a class do myBtn2***

```js
  var btn2 = document.getElementById('myBtn2') 
  var showTag = document.querySelector('.controls') //pegar a div com class 'controls' sóp ara testarmos no final
  btn2.addEventListener('click', addClass)//Event Listener de click o mesmo evento de 'onclick' na tag html, (ao clicar executar a função addClass)

  function addClass() {
    if (btn2.getAttribute('class') == '.carousel-control-next-icon') {
     btn2.removeAttribute('class')
    } // Vai apagar a class se o valor atributo class do label btn2 é igual a .carousel-control-next-icon, e se for ele apenas vai substituir pelo mesmo e não adicionar mais class
    else {
      btn2.setAttribute('class', '.carousel-control-next-icon')
    } //Caso a class do label btn2 não for igual a .carousel-cont... ele vai adicionar uma class. Adicionando na tag label um class=".carousel-control.next-icon"
    alert(showTag.innerHTML)// Só Para testar e conferir se a class está no label
  }
```

```css
          #player{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40%;
            right: 40px;
            z-index: 999;
          }
          .controls i{
            background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0%,#ddd 100%);
            padding: 11px 13px 11px 13px;
            border-radius: 50%;
          }
          .controls i{
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #178F5D;
            text-align: center;
            transition: 1s;
            transition: 100ms all ease;
          }
          .controls label {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
          }
          #myBtn,
          #myBtn2 {
            display: none;
          }
          #play:checked ~ .controls #myBtn,
          #pause:checked ~ .controls #myBtn2 {
            display: block;
          }
          [name="player"] {
            display: none;
          }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="player">
     <input type="radio" name="player" id="pause" checked>
     <input type="radio" name="player" id="play">
     <div class="controls">
       <label id="myBtn2" for="play"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
       <label id="myBtn" for="pause" onclick="addClass()"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                  
     </div>
    </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado